# How to apply my jQuery plugin to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins

I am building an app that dynamically generates section elements styled as post it notes. I am configuring this app to take the form of a jQuery plugin. The function to generate the sections works fine, but I am unable to render my default plugin styling options onto the sections. Basically, my plugin does not seem to apply to my dynamically created elements. Any recommendations on how to fix this? See Code below. Thanks!

```
index.html

    <div id="mylist"></div>

    <input type="button" id="NewElement" value="New Element">

    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script>
      $("section").newNote();
    </script>
```

```
script.js

(function ( $ ) {
$.fn.newNote = function(options) {

    $('#NewElement').on('click',function(){
        $('#mylist').append("<section></section><br />");
    });

        var settings = $.extend({
            radius: 3,
            border: 0,
            background: "linear-gradient(#f9efaf, #f7e98d)",
            resize: "none",
            width: "20%",
            padding: 20,
            overflow: "hidden",
            height: 200,
            margin: "1%",
            float: "left"
        }, options );

        return this.css({
            radius: settings.radius,
            background: settings.background,
            resize: settings.resize,
            width: settings.width,
            padding: settings.padding,
            overflow: settings.overflow,
            height: settings.height,
            margin: settings.margin,
            float: settings.float
        });
};
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: the term you are looking for is event delegation

Comment: You effectively need to reinitialise your iife when you create a new element. It can't affect the elements that are going to be created int he future.

Comment: @JaromandaX how would you recommend using event delegation to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your method as shown in below code snippet

```js
(function ( $ ) {

 $(document).on('click', '#NewElement', function () {
        $('#mylist').append("<section></section><br />");
        $('section').newNote();
 });

$.fn.newNote = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            radius: 3,
            border: 0,
            background: "linear-gradient(#f9efaf, #f7e98d)",
            resize: "none",
            width: "20%",
            padding: 20,
            overflow: "hidden",
            height: 200,
            margin: "1%",
            float: "left"
        }, options );

        return this.css({
            radius: settings.radius,
            background: settings.background,
            resize: settings.resize,
            width: settings.width,
            padding: settings.padding,
            overflow: settings.overflow,
            height: settings.height,
            margin: settings.margin,
            float: settings.float
        });
};
}( jQuery ));
```

```html
<div id="mylist"></div>
<input type="button" id="NewElement" value="New Element">
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks! However, I was hoping to have a setup where the function to generate the section elements remained inside script.js, while the initializing code stayed in the html file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: unfortunately this wasn't fully resolved. Any idea how I can keep the element generating function inside the script.js and just have the initializing code between the script tags in the HTML page?

Comment: Would you please show the code script.js file and , are you using same file in different pages also

Comment: I updated my code above. One is titled index.html, the other is script.js.

Comment: Updated my answer , Please check it and let me know whether it works or not

Comment: This works, but using this same setup I was hoping that $('section').newNote(); could be in between script tags inside the HTML file, instead of the script.js file. How do I set it up like that?

Comment: the idea here is to basically set it up so that the user can simply on initialize the code with $('section').newNote(); between script tags on the html side.

Comment: You can't intialize the code $('section').newNote(); between script tag because this code will be excuted only at the time of DOM render, You have to reinitialise the section every time it is added dynamically.That's why added above code in click event of button.